# Hide certain dates

Tags: php

How can I hide certain dates if, for example, I don't want the 27.12 to be displayed? Currently it runs so that this loop runs continuously and no matter which If query I insert the 27 is still displayed. I would like to insert an array with several dates that should not be displayed.

```
$date = time() + (86400*3);
$b = 5; // Anzahl Schleifendurchläufe
$cb = "4";
for($i = 0; $i < $b; $i++) {
    $cb++;
    echo '<li><input type="checkbox" id="'.$cb.'" name="Datum" value="'.date('d.m.Y', $date).'"/>'.date('d.m.Y', $date).'
    <label class="ort" for="'.$cb.'"><img src="https://www.tintencenter.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/kalender-678x381.jpg" /><br><br></label>
</li>';
    $date += 86400;
```

@RiggsFolly That was exactly my thought, but then nothing is shown from the loop anymore instead of just this date. But then all other entries are also not visible ... I am concerned that the other entries are still visible, only the specific dates are not. Or it just happens in the loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $b; $i++) {
    $cb++;
    if (date('d.m', $date) == '31.12'){
        echo '<li><input type="checkbox" id="'.$cb.'" name="Datum" value="'.date('d.m.Y', $date).'"/>'.date('d.m.Y', $date).'
        <label class="ort" for="'.$cb.'"><img src="https://www.tintencenter.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/kalender-678x381.jpg" /><br><br></label>
        </li>';
        $date += 86400;
    }else{
        echo '<li><input type="checkbox" id="'.$cb.'" name="Datum" value="'.date('d.m.Y', $date).'"/>'.date('d.m.Y', $date).'
        <label class="ort" for="'.$cb.'"><img src="https://www.tintencenter.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/kalender-678x381.jpg" /><br><br></label>
        </li>';
        $date += 86400;
    }
```

Comment: An if statement would be the first thing to try

Comment: I've already done this, only I'm either too stupid for it or have wrongly integrated this if statement in the foreach loop.

Comment: `if (date('d.m', $date) == '21.12'){`

Comment: @RiggsFolly That was exactly my thought, but then nothing is shown from the loop anymore instead of just this date. But then all other entries are also not visible ... I am concerned that the other entries are still visible, only the specific dates are not. Or it just happens in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple IF should allow you to NOT print one of the dates

```
$aDay = 86400*3;

$date = time() + $aDay;
$b = 5; // Anzahl Schleifendurchläufe
$cb = "4";

echo 'Loop without any checks'.PHP_EOL;
for($i = 0; $i < $b; $i++) {
    echo date('d.m.Y',$date) . PHP_EOL;
    $date += $aDay;
}

//reset date and pick one of the dates that will occur and stop it

$date = time() + $aDay;
echo PHP_EOL.'Loop with checks'.PHP_EOL;
for($i = 0; $i < $b; $i++) {
    $cb++;
    if (date('d.m', $date) == '07.01'){
        echo 'Dont print it ' . date('d.m.Y', $date) . PHP_EOL;
    }else{
        echo 'Print it ' .date('d.m.Y', $date) . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $date += $aDay;
}
```

RESULT

```
Loop without any checks
01.01.2020
04.01.2020
07.01.2020
10.01.2020
13.01.2020

Loop with checks
Print it 01.01.2020
Print it 04.01.2020
Dont print it 07.01.2020
Print it 10.01.2020
Print it 13.01.2020
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's the solution .... I was close but had my eyes closed.